# Possible to set default gateway to look like something else in a browser?

Tags: router

I currently have a NETGEAR Router. When you go to the default gateway it shows the GUI for setting up and editing settings etc in a browser. I would like to change what that page looks like. Is it possible to create my own HTML/CSS page as the home page or index and have a link or button that takes you to the GUI?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It has to be the default gateway way that looks different. I do not want to change the default gateway and set the old one to a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI you speak of is stored in the device's firmware. Typically, making changes to the GUI is not something supported by networking hardware.

If your device can be flashed with something like Tomato or DD-WRT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_firmware_projects), you could probably modify the GUI from one of those projects to your liking and install it on your device.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed to know.